# No matches for kind "IngressClass" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I tried to install the NGINX Ingress Controller via Helm. Yes i am using Helm 3.x so it should work. I also was following the guideline in the [NGINX DOCS](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) , but the problem is i always get an error when i am using this line

```
helm install my-release nginx-stable/nginx-ingress
```

Error

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "IngressClass" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

We are using out K8s Cluster with Version 1.22.0. I also tried to install the chart with a values.yaml file. But it is the same issues. Any idea ? Help would be perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` is no longer supported in Kubernetes v1.22 according to the [deprecation guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingressclass-v122). It is possible that the helm resources for nginx controller are not yet updated with the latest API versions.

The [helm charts on their master](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/deployments/helm-chart/templates/controller-ingress-class.yaml#L1) are updated with the latest API version. Did you try installing the controller from source?

Other option would be to downgrade your Kubernetes version to 1.21 or lower version and try installing using helm resources.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and overcame it by changing my ingress yaml file to match the minimal one at:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

(The main change is moving to "v1" instead of "v1beta").
My Server version is: v1.25.3